# Rounding differences with Python, C, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, c, rounding-error

I'm trying to multiply numbers and different languages are producing different results. Here is the math problem:

```
x = 3.0524116
y = 57325
z = x * y
```

With Python (and also JavaScript), `z` is `174979.49123897057`. Demonstration code is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float32(3.0524116)
y = np.uint32(57325)
z = x * y
print(z)
```

With C, `z` is `174979.500000`. Demonstration code is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 3.0524116f;
    unsigned int y = 57325;
    float z = x * y;
    printf("%f\n", z);
    return 0; 
}
```

Now, when `z` is rounded to an integer in C, buffers that had been initialized in Python overflow and the whole thing goes over the cliff... Anyway, what is going on here? Why aren't the results the same?

Comment: Show us the full C/C++ code, including how the value is printed.

Comment: What do you mean by "when z is rounded to an integer in C/C++, buffers that had been initialized in Python overflow and the whole thing goes over the cliff"?  Why would rounding a value in C affect Python code?

Comment: The mechanism that prints numbers in any language may make its own decisions about how to do it. The numbers in actuality are binary floating-point values, so the decimal representation is always going to be an approximation. (well, often, if not "always".)

Comment: Are you using a `float` (~7 digits of precision) or a `double` (~16 digits of precision)? On your standard PC, a `double` will have exactly the same precision as a JavaScript number.

Comment: Your python test is still not equivalent to your C test. See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce your results if I use `float` in C, rather than `double`. Python's `float` type and JavaScript's `Number` are actually implemented with C `double`s, so if you want C to behave the same, use `double`, not `float`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong type.

As others have pointed out, Python and JavaScript both used `double`s as opposed to `float`s. So for an accurate comparison with Python and Javascript, I tried this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double x = 3.0524115349144454, y = 57325;
    printf("%.12lf\n", x * y);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the output is `174979.491238970571`. That's *exactly* the same as `174979.49123897057` (except with 1 extra digit in C). So as you can see, it is the same, you were just using the wrong type (most probably, it would be good if you could clarify this in an edit).

I also ran the equivalent programs in Python and Javascript just to make sure, and the output was the same. I *also* ran the same C program except I replaced the `double` with `float`, and I got the output of `174979.500000000000`. So again, this is making me think you used `float`, though it would be good if you could clarify.

**EDIT:** I just noticed the edit you've made. However, the C tests and the Python tests are still not equivalent. In your python example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float32(3.0524116)
y = np.uint32(57325)
z = x * y
print(z)
```

`x * y`  still returns a double-precision result which is then stored in a double precision `float` `z`. For an accurate test, you would have to replace `z = x * y` with `z = np.float32(x * y)`. When I try the Python program with the required change, I get `174979.5`, the same result as with C using `float`s. As for Javascript, I don't know how you've tested that or how you could use single-precision `float`s in it. I hardly know anything about the language, so I can't say really.

Comment: This answer is correct. In Python, I was not expecting multiplication of a 32-bit float and an integer to return a 64-bit float.

Comment: @fiftytwocards seems like an intentional thing to me. I checked the type with `type(z)` and it is `numpy.float64` instead of normal `float`, probably done in case you needed the extra precision, and it wouldn't be too hard to cast back afterwards.